# Change Image opacity when Touched Swift 3 Xcode

Tags: ios, swift

I have a play button on my game and when i touch it i would like the image opacity to change or something just so that the user knows they have touched it.

Must be easy for somebody that knows how!

Comment: What type of object is the button? A `UIButton`? Are you using the storyboard?

Comment: its actually an image dragged into the story board, just wanted to know if there was a way to change the opacity of the image on touch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to change opacity in is to use the `UIView` `alpha` property like so:

```
yourView.alpha = 0.5 // 50% opacity
yourView.alpha = 0 // 0% opacity - completely transparent
yourView.alpha = 1 // 100% opacity - completely opaque
```

Comment: Okay, so i could change the .alpha value on a touch command? (when image is touched the alpha changes?

Comment: Yes. You need to register the touch event on the button - and then when it's triggered just change the alpha.

Answer (score 0):

You can animate the button opacity inside the function which is executed when the button is pressed,

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {

```
sender.alpha = 0.5
```

}

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {

```
sender.alpha = 1
```

}

where sender refers to the UIButton.